# How to set Frame of CCsprite in Cocoa2d

Tags: iphone

I have to change the Image of CCsprite i used CCtexture2d for that it replace the image but image is compressed because the first image i set is small and the second image is big.any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the texture rect to the new size with this method:

```
-(void) setTextureRect:(CGRect) rect;
```

Comment: This will just set the frame of the texture/sprite with frame (0,0,sprite_width,sprite_height) nothing else. Can you give some other  way for achieving this..